# How to format text of a title attribute

Tags: jquery, html

I have several links across several pages that have a title attribute already set. I need to make the text of the tooltips lowercase in all instances. What is the best way to achieve this without modifying every link across my website?

`<a href="#" title="Make ME lowErCase!"/>Some link</a>`

EDIT: Sorry, I should have been more clear, I tried using:

`$("a[title]").css("text-transform","lowercase");`

but that only made the visible text of my links lowercase, not the title tooltip.

Comment: JavaScript is your friend.

Comment: I'd ask, though, why don't you want to modify the links? Just because it might take a bit of time? Putting some kind of band-aid patch to get the behavior you want isn't necessarily better than taking the time to maintain clean code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
$("a[title]").attr("title",function() {
    return $(this).attr("title").toLowerCase();
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! How returning and calling "toLowerCase()" differ from just doing $("a[title]").attr("title").toLowerCase() ?

Comment: @Sg1456 -- The above code returns a lower case string of your title, you never actually set the `title` attribute. My code sets the attribute as well.